# How to change column value in pandas based on contains condition with creation service field for every row?

Tags: pandas

i have following dataframe example

```
    Full address                                        City
1   New York 11706 · 9460 York Ave. Brooklyn.         New York
2   169 Rocky River Dr. Fresno                        California
```

I want to edit every value in Full address column. If value in City row in Full address -> change Full address value to City and mark this row. The result should looks like this

```
     Full address                    City       Marked
1      New York                     New York       1
2  169 Rocky River Dr. Fresno      California      0
```

The result looks like this because in first row value in City row New York presents in Full address and this row marked as 1 because row has been edited. The second row stays the same because Full address value doesn't contains City value, so this row marked as 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df['Marked'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['City'] in x['Full address'], axis=1).astype(int)

df.loc[df['Marked']==1, 'Full address'] = df['City']
```

Output:

```
                 Full address        City  Marked
1                    New York    New York       1
2  169 Rocky River Dr. Fresno  California       0
```

Answer (score 1):

A little faster:

```
df['Marked'] = [1 if c in a else 0 for a, c in zip(df['Full address'], df['City'])]
df.loc[df['Marked']==1, 'Full address'] = df['City']
```

Output:

```
                 Full address        City  Marked
1                    New York    New York       1
2  169 Rocky River Dr. Fresno  California       0
```